I want a tester for camera--battery---keyboard---sound. that will start in the startup of the device
I have to deal with hundreds of devices (laptops and desktops) in a day and I have to check the hardware. I found a tester in a used old laptop that used Ubuntu and I want to recreate it.


What is the name of the executable of this Taster app? Where did you get it? Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Yad is a good choice.
